# jQuery - disable / removing javascript from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe inside my page with the following code:

```
...
<script  language="javascript"  type="text/javascript">

    function clearMessage() {
       window.print();
    }

    $(function () {
        var state=0;
        if (state==1) {
            window.print();
            window.opener.location = window.opener.location.href;
        }

        var sentToPrint=0;
        if (sentToPrint==1)
        {
            window.print();
            window.opener.location = window.opener.location.href;
        }

    });

    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        if (('1') == '1') {
            window.opener.location = window.opener.location.href;
            //window.opener.location = 'mainPage.aspx'
        }
    }
</script>
...
```

Basically what it does is printing the page on form submit or if I having 
"print=1" in the URL, which in my case I sending "print=0" because I don't want the iframe to be printed.

so I want to disable this part or removing this part form my parent page using jQuery.

Is there any way to disable the printing function or removing it from the iframe?

thank you!

Comment: have you got access to the iframe?

Comment: no, the source in the iframe is not my website

Comment: without access to the source code you cant do anything via Javascript due to CORS restrictions

Comment: but I can change the HTML, I can remove parts of it, is it not possible also with javascript on the page?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `iframe` part to be printed then use print media query `@media print` to hide that iframe while printing

```
@media print {
   iframe {
      display: none;
   }
}
```

Comment: i dont want to print at all, the iframe runs 'window.print();' if you submitting a form inside of him, i want to submit this form and disable the printing

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found how to submit the form without printing the page,
I just copied the inputs from the iframe and submitted the form using ajax

```
$('#myFrame').one('load', function(){
    var eventTriger     = $("#myFrame").contents().find("#__EVENTTARGET").val();
    var eventArgu       = $("#myFrame").contents().find("#__EVENTARGUMENT").val();
    var viewState       = $("#myFrame").contents().find("#__VIEWSTATE").val();

    var json = {
        '__EVENTTARGET'     : eventTriger,
        '__EVENTARGUMENT'   : eventArgu,
        '__VIEWSTATE'       : viewState
    };

    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "url",
      type: "POST",
      data: json,
      dataType: "html"
    });
});
```